# Typescript module import with configuration file

Tags: node.js, typescript

I would to like forge the path to access node_modules with some configuration file. It seems it's not possible to do the thing below, how should I forge my path then?

The aim is to write absolute path to some node_modules ( cause some files are splitted so this is needed).

```
import someFileSettings from "./../../models/someFileSettings";
import * as request from JSON.stringify(someFileSettings .somePathIneed+"request");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible, because TypeScript modules follow the standard ES6 modules. To do that, there is a *module loader API*, based on promises.

Here is the explanation from [the book of  Dr. Axel Rauschmayer](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_can-i-use-a-variable-to-specify-from-which-module-i-want-to-import):

> **16.9.1 Can I use a variable to specify from which module I want to import?**
>
> The import statement is completely static: its module specifier is always fixed. If you want to dynamically determine what module to load, you need to use [the programmatic loader API](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_module-loader-api):
>
> ```
> const moduleSpecifier = 'module_' + Math.random();
> System.import(moduleSpecifier)
> .then(the_module => {
>     // Use the_module
> })
> ```

... but, notice this warning:

> The module loader API is not part of the ES6 standard